# android build failing as soon as react-native-pdf-lib is installed

Tags: react-native, android-build

As soon as I install react-native-pdf-lib the android build starts to fail in react native, it says

```
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not find com.tom_roush:pdfbox-android:1.8.9.1.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/tom_roush/pdfbox-android/1.8.9.1/pdfbox-android-1.8.9.1.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/tom_roush/pdfbox-android/1.8.9.1/pdfbox-android-1.8.9.1.pom
       - file:/Users/yashworldproductpvtltd/example/DocsAndIDScanner/node_modules/jsc-android/dist/com/tom_roush/pdfbox-android/1.8.9.1/pdfbox-android-1.8.9.1.pom
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/tom_roush/pdfbox-android/1.8.9.1/pdfbox-android-1.8.9.1.pom
       - https://www.jitpack.io/com/tom_roush/pdfbox-android/1.8.9.1/pdfbox-android-1.8.9.1.pom
     Required by:
         project :app > project :react-native-pdf-lib

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.
```

I have already tried solutions mentioned [solution1](https://github.com/Hopding/react-native-pdf-lib/issues/97) and [solution2](https://github.com/Hopding/react-native-pdf-lib/issues/27),I am new to react native and I don't seem to find any solution,
I want functionality to create edit and merge pdfs in my app